# NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems throws exception

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

If I set only one right button on the NavBar it works perfectly.
But when I'm trying to set more than one button, they showed up, but clicking on them throws exceptions.

```
EventHandler pickPhotoClickHandler = (s,e) => {}; //Do nothing
var pickPhotoBtn = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Camera, pickPhotoClickHandler);

EventHandler sendBtnClickHandler = (s, e) => {}; //Do nothing
var sendBtn = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, sendBtnClickHandler);

NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem (pickPhotoBtn, animated:true); // This works

var btns = new UIBarButtonItem[]{sendBtn,pickPhotoBtn}; // This doesn't 
NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(btns,true);       // go very far
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: interesting - I didn't think a NavBar supported more than one button on the right

Comment: @Jason: This is new functionality introduced in iOS 5.0 (which I found out when I tried to use it in a 4.3 app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix that by creating new class derived from `UIbarButtonItem` and defining a constructor with IntPtr

```
public class UIBarBtn : UIBarButtonItem{
        public UIBarBtn(IntPtr handle):base(handle){}
        public UIBarBtn(UIBarButtonSystemItem si, EventHandler handler):base(si,handler){}
}
```

Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

It works if you want to add multiple right buttons for iOS < 5.0

Tried and tested! :D